# Tensorflow multilabel accuracy measures

Tags: python, tensorflow, metrics, multilabel-classification

I'm dealing with a multilabel problem with 11 possible labels.

y_true and y_pred are tensors of shape [batch_size, 11] where the possible labels are represented as 0's and 1's, like:

per example, batch_size=4

```
  y_true=[[0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],
           [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1],
           [0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
           [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]]

   y_pred= [[0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
           [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1],
           [1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
           [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]]
```

I've been searching but I have lots of questions, I would like to have 3 types of accuracy:

1. a "class accuracy", i mean if the correct labels are [class1, class2, class3,..., class11].

   ```
    y_true_class1=[0,0,0,0]  
    y_pred_class1=[0,0,1,1]
    acc_class1=2/4
   ```
2. the mean of accuracy per element in batch, such as:

   y_true_batch_element_1= [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]

   y_pred_batch_element_1= [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]

   acc_element_1 = 10/11

and then:

```
mean(acc_element_1, acc_element_2, ..., acc_element_n)
```

3. all the classes must be predicted correctly, and in this case, we would receive:

   `acc=1/4` (element2 was the only one that was completely
   right)`

how can I get each one of these accuracies with TensorFlow?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                               [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                               [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                               [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                               [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                               [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                               [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

This is your first and second metric:

```
tf.divide(tf.reduce_sum(
    tf.cast(
        tf.equal(y_true, y_pred), tf.int32), axis=1), 
    tf.shape(y_true)[1])
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([0.90909091, 1., 0.90909091, 0.81818182])>
```

This is your third metric:

```
tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(y_true, y_pred), axis=1), tf.float32), axis=0)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.25>
```

I hope I got them right. Your two firsts look the same to me.